Proof: $M(x)= \{ y \in \Omega(x) | v(x) \leq f(x,y) \} $ nonempty iff nonempty in neighborhood of $x$
The following theorem is given by Hogan (Point to Set Maps in Mathematical Programming)

with $v(x) = sup_ {x \in \Omega(x) } f(x,y)$
where $f: X \times Y \rightarrow  [ -\infty, \infty ]$
and let $M(x)= \{ y \in \Omega(x) | v(x) \leq f(x,y) \} $ and
$M^* (x,\epsilon) := \{ y \in \Omega(x) | v(x) \leq f(x,y) + \epsilon \}$
I am struggling to understand the following part of the proof where we try to show that if $M(\bar{x})$ is nonempty, then it follows that $M^*(x^k,\epsilon)$ is nonempty.

Firstly, we assume that $M^*(x^k,\epsilon)$ is empty which means that for all $y \in \Omega(x^k)$ it holds that
$\sup_{y \in \Omega(x^k)} f(x^k,y) > f(x^k,y) + \epsilon$. How exactly do we use the openness of $\Omega(x^k)$ to derive the existence of a sequence $z^j$ with $||z^j|| \rightarrow \infty$ then?
Also, how do we derive condition (a) and condition (b) and where is the contradiction? I am really stuck at this part of the proof.
